# Issues with behaviorally-defined FET-like component in LTspice

Tags: transistors, mosfet, ltspice, simulation

I am developing an LTspice model for a novel transistor that behaves much like a MOSFET.  But in simulations, I get a behavior I don't understand.

I've modeled this device using a behavioral current source using a particular form of the transconductance equation:

\$ I=\large\frac{Channel_W}{Channel_L}\small*Channel_d*u*C*(Vgs-Vt0)^2 \$

When I sweep the gate voltage, I want to see a change in the current corresponding to the saturation regime--I haven't modeled the linear regime yet--but instead, my model always drops from 1A to 0A across the sweep.

Is this an issue with LTspice that I don't understand or have I made a silly mistake here?

Attaching my schematic for the test circuit and subcircuit, netlist and simulation below. Thanks!

---

Netlist:

```
* /Users/Owner/Documents/LTspice/OECT/OECT_test.asc
XX1 Gate 0 N001 oect_model
V1 Gate 0 V
R1 0 N001 .1

* block symbol definitions
.subckt oect_model Gate Source Drain
B1 Source Drain I=(Channel_W/Channel_L)*Channel_d*uC*(V(Gate, Source)-Vt0)^2
.param Channel_W=1u Channel_L=5m Channel_d=5u
.param uC=75T Vt0=0
.ends oect_model

.DC v1 -1 2 .01
.backanno
.end
```

[image: Test circuit with sub-circuit]

[image: Sub-circuit schematic]

[image: Simulation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your answer is found within the built-in LTspice Help (press <kbd>F1</kbd> to bring it up) under `B. Arbitrary Behavioral Voltage or Current Sources`.  Check the 2nd table on that help page.  It looks to me like you're unintentionally using an XOR operation in your equation and should be using the double asterisk (`**`) instead.

[image]

Comment: That did it. Thank you!